# Why is this not iterable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typed-arrays

Hello I am writing an angular app. I have a Node API returning data which I am trying to chart using Chart.js. I am getting my data from the API and it returns an object like this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "_id": "62716061f6897b637f59ba9e",
    "created": "2022-05-03T17:03:29.459Z",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Air Temperature",
        "imperial": 66.42499542,
        "metric": 19.0625,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62716061f6897b637f59ba9f"
      },
      {
        "name": "Outside Air Temperature",
        "imperial": 65.75,
        "metric": 18.6875,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62716061f6897b637f59baa0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Water Temperature",
        "imperial": 65.75,
        "metric": 18.75,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62716061f6897b637f59baa1"
      }
    ],
    "settings": [
      {
        "name": "in1",
        "onValue": 80,
        "offValue": 78,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62716061f6897b637f59baa2"
      },
      {
        "name": "in2",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62716061f6897b637f59baa3"
      },
      {
        "name": "in3",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62716061f6897b637f59baa4"
      },
      {
        "name": "in4",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62716061f6897b637f59baa5"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  },
  "1": {
    "_id": "62715f33f6897b637f59ba92",
    "created": "2022-05-03T16:58:27.064Z",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Air Temperature",
        "imperial": 66.3125,
        "metric": 19.0625,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62715f33f6897b637f59ba93"
      },
      {
        "name": "Outside Air Temperature",
        "imperial": 65.63749695,
        "metric": 18.6875,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62715f33f6897b637f59ba94"
      },
      {
        "name": "Water Temperature",
        "imperial": 65.75,
        "metric": 18.75,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62715f33f6897b637f59ba95"
      }
    ],
    "settings": [
      {
        "name": "in1",
        "onValue": 80,
        "offValue": 78,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715f33f6897b637f59ba96"
      },
      {
        "name": "in2",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715f33f6897b637f59ba97"
      },
      {
        "name": "in3",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715f33f6897b637f59ba98"
      },
      {
        "name": "in4",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715f33f6897b637f59ba99"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  },
  "2": {
    "_id": "62715e04f6897b637f59ba72",
    "created": "2022-05-03T16:53:24.706Z",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Air Temperature",
        "imperial": 66.19999695,
        "metric": 19.0625,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62715e04f6897b637f59ba73"
      },
      {
        "name": "Outside Air Temperature",
        "imperial": 65.63749695,
        "metric": 18.6875,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62715e04f6897b637f59ba74"
      },
      {
        "name": "Water Temperature",
        "imperial": 65.75,
        "metric": 18.75,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62715e04f6897b637f59ba75"
      }
    ],
    "settings": [
      {
        "name": "in1",
        "onValue": 80,
        "offValue": 78,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715e04f6897b637f59ba76"
      },
      {
        "name": "in2",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715e04f6897b637f59ba77"
      },
      {
        "name": "in3",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715e04f6897b637f59ba78"
      },
      {
        "name": "in4",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715e04f6897b637f59ba79"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  },
  "3": {
    "_id": "62715cd6f6897b637f59ba66",
    "created": "2022-05-03T16:48:22.086Z",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Air Temperature",
        "imperial": 66.19999695,
        "metric": 19,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62715cd6f6897b637f59ba67"
      },
      {
        "name": "Outside Air Temperature",
        "imperial": 65.63749695,
        "metric": 18.6875,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62715cd6f6897b637f59ba68"
      },
      {
        "name": "Water Temperature",
        "imperial": 65.75,
        "metric": 18.75,
        "controlStatus": false,
        "_id": "62715cd6f6897b637f59ba69"
      }
    ],
    "settings": [
      {
        "name": "in1",
        "onValue": 80,
        "offValue": 78,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715cd6f6897b637f59ba6a"
      },
      {
        "name": "in2",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715cd6f6897b637f59ba6b"
      },
      {
        "name": "in3",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715cd6f6897b637f59ba6c"
      },
      {
        "name": "in4",
        "onValue": 0,
        "offValue": 0,
        "status": "",
        "unitType": "Temp",
        "_id": "62715cd6f6897b637f59ba6d"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

I am trying to iterate over this to parse my data points but I am getting errors. Here is my code:

```
  constructDataSet(input: IGreenhouseData[]) {
    let labels: string[] = [];
    let imperial: number[] = [];
    let metric: number[] = [];
    let datasets: IDataSet[] = [];

    for (let item of input) {
      for (let dataPoint of item.items) {
        labels.push(dataPoint.name);
        imperial.push(dataPoint.imperial);
        metric.push(dataPoint.metric);
      }
      let newDataSet: IDataSet = {
        label: 'Imperial',
        data: imperial,
      };
      datasets.push(newDataSet);

      newDataSet = {
        label: 'Metric',
        data: metric,
      };
      datasets.push(newDataSet);
    }

    this.data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: datasets,
    };
  }
```

This is the error:
ERROR TypeError: input is not iterable

Comment: 1. Paste the input as valid json in the question 2. Which line gives you the error?

Comment: input is not an array

Comment: @NicholasK Line7 (the for loop) gives the error.

Comment: @Nonik 'input' is the variable name with this JSON data in it. That is not an array?

Comment: `input` is an *Object* **not** an array.

Comment: I see now thank you both. I will look into fixing that. I did not even pay attention to the brackets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input` is not an *array*, but an *object*. Change the for-loop to:

```
for (let item of Object.values(input)) {  
   
   /*rest of the code*/ 

}
```

so the iteration is done over the object *values* rather than the object itself.